# IAM policy for API Gateway invocation based on Cognito Identity ID

Tags: amazon-iam, amazon-cognito, aws-api-gateway

I want to allow Cognito authenticated users to invoke API Gateway endpoint but restrict them to their own resources like
 '`/users/<IdentityID>/*`'.

I have prepared an IAM role like this.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "execute-api:Invoke"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:execute-api:ap-northeast-1:*:MyAPIID/*/*/users/${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}*"
            ]
        }
}
```

But on this setting, I get a 403 error when I try to invoke.

If I replace the `${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}` to actual Identity ID (like `ap-northeast-1%3Ad8515ae9-62b5-4cba-af5c-195f5d7e1d07`), it works.

We cannot use `${cognito-identity.amazonaws.com:sub}` on API Gateway resource, can we?

Answer (score 1):

That is correct. Currently, it's only a shortcut for S3 and DynamoDB.

Comment: I see. Thanks!
The idea of including identity id might be inherently bad..
I'll check the authority by another methods.